# `this` keyword is undefined in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, this, global

I am having trouble understanding "this" keyword behaviors in JavaScript (NodeJS - v16.19.1). According to [this site](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-this/), "this" keyword in the global execution context will reference the global object:

```js
// this is my entire index.js file, I run "node index.js"
// global scope
console.log(this === globalThis); // this should be true but it is false.
console.log(this); // undefined
```

Running it in NodeJS (v16.19.1) in WSL 2 (windows 10)
Is there an explanation for this? Thank you!

Comment: Where are you running it? I get `this === globalThis //true`

Comment: I think you should compare to global instead if globalThis

Comment: It isn't clear if the code you are running is on the REPL, in a CommonJS module or in an ECMAScript module. Context matters.

Comment: I have compared "this" to both "globalThis" & "global". I am running NodeJS (v16.19.1) in WSL 2 (windows 10).

Comment: In a CommonJS or ES Module, [a module is **not** in the global scope, unlike most scripts in a browser](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v20.x/api/globals.html#global). That's why `global` (deprecated) and `globalThis` exist.

Comment: You stumbled upon one of the most confusing aspects of javascript. But generally speaking `this` should refer to your current context. You can always test it out by using `console.log(this)`. The first question you should ask yourself is why you need it at all?

Answer (score -1):

This behavior is because when a module file is called then `this` get binned to the return value of [GetThisBinding()](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-module-environment-records-getthisbinding), which return undefined.

However, if you will run the same code on browser then it will return true.

Comment: Both node.js and browsers implement the same ECMAScript `GetThisBinding`, why would they return anything different?

Comment: @Bergi In browsers `this` keyword finds its value from `ResolveThisBinding()`, however, ECMAScript does this for `global`.